# Python flask aligning the form to the center

Tags: python, flask

I want to align a form to the center this:

[image: THE FORM]

but my code as you can see is pretty beginner friendly and most of the answers I see is higher level code and doesn't work with me.

The code:

```html
{% extends "base.html" %} {% block title %}Sign up{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
<form method="POST">
  <h3 align="center">Put your Goods</h3>
  <div>
    <label for="email">Email Address</label>
    <input 
      type="email"
      id="email" 
      name="email" 
      placeholder="Enter Email"
    />
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="firstName">First Name</label>
    <input 
      type="text"
      id="firstName" 
      name="firstName" 
      placeholder="Enter first name"
    />
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="password1">Password</label>
    <input 
      type="password"
      id="password1" 
      name="password1" 
      placeholder="Enter password"
    />
  </div>
  <br />
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```